# MongoDB trouble, is both way references a thing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a website built with node.js + mongoDB (mongoose). I'm having a bit trouble in the design of the database.

I want to have 2 logins, one for institutions and another for professionals. Do I need to double reference them (like the professional has a ref to Inst and an institution has a ref to the professional)?

For instance, If I want to display the list of all professionals when I login with an institution is trivial but if I don't ref the institution on the User (professional) is not so simple. So which one is better? Having code to find the user in every institution and get its institution name or both referencing each other and then do a populate?

If I pick both referencing each other, is there some way to guarantee that both of them will always be linked and having no broken only one way references?

Code:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    status : Boolean,
    institution: { type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Inst' }
});


mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User');

var instSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name : String,
    professional : [{ type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'}]
});

mongoose.model('Inst', instSchema);
var Inst = mongoose.model('Inst');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just merge `instSchema` into `userSchema` as below, with additional `user_type` to indicate which type this user belong to, `Professional` or `Institutions`. Also one new `related_user` to store the other related `User` documents

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    status : Boolean,
    user_type: {type: String, enum: ['Prof', 'Inst']},
    related_user: [{ type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'}]
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

Comment: That could be a solution for my problem but institutions will have distinct properties than professional. On the another hand, I could just ref them to another table that has those properties though.

Comment: @Condward, since mongodb is schemaless, it could be ok with some distinct properties in one schema. However, it could be bad idea, if there are many fields in `instSchema`...

Comment: What if I just have new a collection with the professional only properties (if any) and another with just the the institution only properties and then ref those collections from the User?

Comment: Just one more question. If I am professional, I have to reference its institution and if I am an institution I have also to ref that professional.